# Ntheorem: Definitions rendered in italics despite \theoremstyle{definition}

Tags: ntheorem

I am using ntheorem.  The text in my theorems is showing up in italics as expected.  However, the text in my definitions is also italicized and it should not be.  I have used the \theoremstyle{definition} command before I define the definition but the PDF is building as if theorems and definitions both had the same theorem style.  How can I remove the italics from my definitions?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks, thref]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defin}[thm]{Definition}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\section{Section Number One}
\begin{thm}
    I am glad that this is showing up in italics
\end{thm}

\begin{defin}
    Since I have used ``theoremstyle:definition'' in the header of my tex file, I am expecting this not to show up in italics.
\end{defin}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Look in the log file: `LaTeX Warning: Unknown theoremstyle `definition'. Using `plain' on input line 10.`

Answer (score 4):

There is no `definition` style with `ntheorem`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks, thref]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]

\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{defin}[thm]{Definition}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\section{Section Number One}
\begin{thm}
    I am glad that this is showing up in italics
\end{thm}

\begin{defin}
Since I have used ``theoremstyle:definition'' in the header 
of my tex file, I am expecting this not to show up in italics.
\end{defin}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Are you sure about `[subsection]`?